# How to sort an ArrayList of integers in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an array list of integers in java that I am trying to sort, I am using the collection.sort method and for some reason I am getting 2 of each number when it sorts. here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArraySort{
  static ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> numberList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> numberList3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that contains the first list");
    String file1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that contains the second list");
    String file2 = input.nextLine();
    ArraySort x = new ArraySort(file1, file2);
    ArrayList<Integer> mergedlist = x.merge();
    System.out.print("The first list is ");
    print(x.numberList);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The second list is ");
    print(x.numberList2);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("The new combine list is ");
    print(mergedlist);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("The sorted combine list is ");
    print(bubbleSort(mergedlist));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter the key for the split: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The list has been split into 2 lists");
    System.out.print("List 1 is "); 
    print(numberList);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("List 2 is "); 
    print(numberList2);
  }
  public ArraySort(){
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      try {
            s = new Scanner (new File ("list1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } 

      while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
          numberList.add(s.nextInt());
        } else {
          s.next(); // else read the next token
          }
      }
      try {
            s = new Scanner (new File ("list2.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } 

      while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
          numberList2.add(s.nextInt());
        } else {
          s.next(); // else read the next token
          }
      }
  }
  public ArraySort(String x, String y){
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      try {
            s = new Scanner (new File (x)).useDelimiter("\\s+");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } 

      while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
          numberList.add(s.nextInt());
        } else {
          s.next(); // else read the next token
          }
      }
      try {
            s = new Scanner (new File (y)).useDelimiter("\\s+");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } 

      while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
          numberList2.add(s.nextInt());
        } else {
          s.next(); // else read the next token
          }
      }
  }
  public static ArrayList<Integer> bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) { 
     Collections.sort(numbers);
     return numbers;
    }
  public static void print(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){

    System.out.println(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){ 
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i) + "  "); 
      }
  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(){

      for( int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++) {
        numberList3.add(numberList.get(i));
      }
      for( int j = 0; j < numberList2.size(); j++) {
        numberList3.add(numberList2.get(j));
      }   
      return numberList3;
    }

  public static void splitList(int x){
    numberList.clear();
    numberList2.clear();
      for(int i=0;i<numberList3.size();i++){
        if(numberList3.get(i)<=x){
          numberList.add(numberList3.get(i));
        }
        else{
          numberList2.add(numberList3.get(i));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and here is the output when I run it:

```
Enter the name of the file that contains the first list
list1.txt
Enter the name of the file that contains the second list
list2.txt

The first list is 
13  25  34  67  56  10  20  27  2  5  1  45  59  

The second list is 
73  29  14  87  72  100  200  127  22  15  19  145  159  78  

The new combine list is 
13  25  34  67  56  10  20  27  2  5  1  45  59  73  29  14  87  72  100  200  127  22  15  19  145  159  78  

The sorted combine list is 
1  2  5  10  13  14  15  19  20  22  25  27  29  34  45  56  59  67  72  73  78  87  100  127  145  159  200  

Enter the key for the split: 
19

The list has been split into 2 lists
List 1 is 
13  25  34  67  56  10  20  27  2  5  1  45  59  

List 2 is 
73  29  14  87  72  100  200  127  22  15  19  145  159  78
```

I can't figure out why it is doing this

Comment: Presents problem, gives code, gives input, gives output. Only thing missing is expected output, but we should be able to assume that by presenting the problem.  Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `x.merge()` twice. Each time, it will  add `numList1` and `numLlist2`

```
System.out.print("The new combine list is ");
print(x.merge());
System.out.println();

System.out.print("The sorted combine list is ");
print(bubbleSort(x.merge()));
```

Make your `merge()` method return an ArrayList. Then you can do this, instead of the above

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(x.merge);

System.out.print("The new combine list is ");
print(newList);
System.out.println();

System.out.print("The sorted combine list is ");
print(bubbleSort(newList));
```

Comment: Thanks, That fixed it. But my split list method doesn't work right either. Do you know what the error is? I can't figure it out for the life of me

Comment: @JulienKerr , For staters, I don't see you call the method anywhere. You should call it `splitList(key)`, after you get the input for `key`.

Comment: @JulienKerr also please accept answer, as I have answered your original posted question. Thank you.